# How to get div value dynamically with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have to get the value of something when I press an accordion div. This div=" accordion" has this structure:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <? if ($_SESSION[SITE]['user']['id'] == $message['yp_from']) { ?>                                                 <div class="row"><span class="bold">From: </span> <span>Me</span>    
     <span class="grey9"> <?= $this->tools_lib->date_format($message['yp_time']); ?></span>     
  <?  } else { if ($message['yp_state_from'] == 0) {?>
 <div class="row"><span class="bold">From: </span><span><?= $this->tools_lib->name_separate($message['yp_name']) ?></span> 
   <div id="idMens<?= $message['id'] ?>" style="display:none;" class="showNew"><?= $message['id'] ?></div></span>
  <h5 id="new"> New </h5>
        <?} else { ?> 
<div class="row"><span class="bold">From: </span><span><?= $this->tools_lib->name_separate($mensaje['yp_name']) ?></span>
    <? } 
         } ?>
</div>
   <p><?= $message['yp_message'] ?><p>
</div>
```

I want to get · $mensaje['id'] · value from the "div id="idMens"". I was trying to do it with jquery. but I have problems to get the correct value, it always take the first item value, I mean the  last dinamically typed.

Im trying to use this jquery code. but I think is not well formed code..

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.accordion').find('div').click(function(){
                $(this).next().slideToggle();
                $('.showNew').on('click', function() {
                    var idm =this.id; 
                });
                var form_data = { 

                    to: $('#',idm).html()
                }


                $.ajax({
                    url: _baseurl+""+_lang+"/messages/updateState/",         // ruta del controlador y accion
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function(data){ 
                        $('#new').hide();
                    }    
                });
            }).next().hide();
        });
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just dont write comments and any names in any other language than English. Developers from other countries might have to work with your code someday! I'm Ukrainian, not English.

Comment: Sorry, that's true. I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it. I'm fool... it was so easy. I was in the wrong way.

I did it creating other function:

```
 function changeState(id){

                var form_data = {
                    to: id
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: _baseurl+""+_lang+"/messages/updateState/",         // ruta del controlador y accion
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function(data){ 
                        $('#new').hide();
                    }    
                });
            }
```

And calling it in the first div. with onclick. I pass the dinamic id as a parameter and therefore I can use it well.

Thank you